# What can be done to encourage users to read the latest bug reports before posting a bug?

Tags: discussion, meta

For example currently we have seen a half dozen of bug reports for the privileges:

- [The gear icon is in the wrong place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349994/the-gear-icon-is-in-the-wrong-place)
- [Chrome bug: privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349986/chrome-bug-privilege)
- [There a layout problem in the user profile → activity chart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349984/there-a-layout-problem-in-the-user-profile-activity-chart)
- [On profile page, button to switch `tracking your next privilege' looks off.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349976/on-profile-page-button-to-switch-tracking-your-next-privilege-looks-off)
- [Bug in Track Button Chrome View](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349960/bug-in-track-button-chrome-view)
- ["Choose between tracking your next privilege ..." UI is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349958/choose-between-tracking-your-next-privilege-ui-is-broken)
- Possible [more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

What can we do to encourage users reading the latest bugs (and check for duplicates) before posting a bug report?

Maybe some UI if the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag is used?

Comment: Same thing with any other duplicate question: if the poster did not do their research and a simple scan of the question page would have solved their issue, you downvote (as well as vote as a duplicate).

Comment: Note that for every duplicate bug report, there are probably 10 that did not get posted because their potential authors *did* first look to see if this was reported already. These bugs are very in-your-face and easy to spot, so loads of people are heading over to Meta to report them when they occur.

Comment: That gear icon bug was something special though... I counted 14 differents post on the main page today

Comment: Not a whole lot, I think. In my experience this is always an issue with every system I've used. Highly visible bug → loads of duplicate bug reports.

Comment: I suggest mockery and revenge voting.

Comment: Obviously create some sort of badge of shame.  Problem solved forever.

Comment: New Off-Topic flag reason: "It's not a bug, its a feature". @bitnine some people are from the good old collect everything RPG age... give them a Gold badge for 1000 duplicates and they will write them on purpose ;)

Comment: Well, I saw titles referring to "Chrome" and thought "I'm not using Chrome." Then I saw a title referring to a gear icon and looked at that one.

Comment: This just proves how hard it is to write meaningful titles.  Of the titles you list, I can only really understand the bug from 3 of them, and only 2 look like immediate duplicates based on their title.  So a good move here is downvoting or editing bug reports with poor titles.

Comment: While most are dupes don't go down voting them all into oblivion. Some may be more complete or add another way the bug is occurring.